# Como saber a linha exata de um erro de NullReferenceException ao criar uma nova instância de um objeto com várias propriedades

Tags: c#

Essa é uma dúvida que eu sempre tive, mas agora resolvi perguntar.

Se ao criar um novo objeto (como no exemplo abaixo, OcorrenciaRelatorioDTO), for gerado o erro de NullReferenceException, o stack trace não me indica exatamente em que propriedade do objeto o erro ocorreu. Existe uma forma de habilitar ou descobrir isso?

```
var ocorrencias = _db.Ocorrencia.AsEnumerable().Select(ocorrencia => new OcorrenciaRelatorioDTO
{
    Id = ocorrencia.Id,
    Ocorrencia = ocorrencia.NumOcorrencia,
    Protocolo = ocorrencia.Protocolo,
    Tipo = ocorrencia.Tipo?.Descricao,
    Cliente = ocorrencia.EmpresaCliente.sigla.ToUpper(),
    UF = ocorrencia.EmpresaCliente.estado,
    Grupo = ocorrencia.EmpresaCliente.nomeGrupo,
    Representante = ocorrencia.EmpresaRepresentante.nomeFantasia.ToUpper(),
    Filial = ocorrencia.EmpresaFilial.sigla.ToUpper(),
    Km = ocorrencia.Deslocamento,
    Motivo = ocorrencia.Motivo?.Descricao,
    DataHoraAbertura = ocorrencia.DataHoraAbertura,
    Equipamento = ocorrencia.NomeEquipamentoFocus,
    Serie = ocorrencia.Serie,
    DataHoraAgendada = ocorrencia.DataHoraAgendada,
    DataHoraAtendimento = ocorrencia.DataHoraAtendimento,
    DataHoraFechamento = ocorrencia.DataHoraFechamento,
    Status = ocorrencia.Status?.Descricao,
    Solucao = ocorrencia.Solucao?.Descricao,
    Observacao = ocorrencia.Observacao,
    Conclusao = ocorrencia.Conclusao?.Descricao,
    OrdemServico = ocorrencia.OrdemServico,
    Orcamento1 = ocorrencia.NumOrcamento,
    Orcamento2 = ocorrencia.NumOrcamento2,
    CedulasProcessadas = ocorrencia.CedulasProcessadas,
    Tecnico = ocorrencia.OcorrenciaTecnico?.FirstOrDefault().Nome,
    CobrarDeslocamento = ocorrencia.CobrarDeslocamento ? "Sim" : "Não",
    CobrarAtendimento = ocorrencia.CobrarAtendimento ? "Sim" : "Não",
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode instanciar o objeto conforme exemplo abaixo. Assim poderá `debuggar` (depurar) linha-a-linha:

```
OcorrenciaRelatorioDTO ocorrenciaRel = new OcorrenciaRelatorioDTO;

ocorrenciaRel.Id = ocorrencia.Id;
ocorrenciaRel.Ocorrencia = ocorrencia.NumOcorrencia;
ocorrenciaRel.Protocolo = ocorrencia.Protocolo;
ocorrenciaRel.Tipo = ocorrencia.Tipo?.Descricao;
ocorrenciaRel.Cliente = ocorrencia.EmpresaCliente.sigla.ToUpper();
ocorrenciaRel.UF = ocorrencia.EmpresaCliente.estado;
ocorrenciaRel.Grupo = ocorrencia.EmpresaCliente.nomeGrupo;
ocorrenciaRel.Representante = ocorrencia.EmpresaRepresentante.nomeFantasia.ToUpper();
ocorrenciaRel.Filial = ocorrencia.EmpresaFilial.sigla.ToUpper();
ocorrenciaRel.Km = ocorrencia.Deslocamento;
ocorrenciaRel.Motivo = ocorrencia.Motivo?.Descricao;
ocorrenciaRel.DataHoraAbertura = ocorrencia.DataHoraAbertura;
ocorrenciaRel.Equipamento = ocorrencia.NomeEquipamentoFocus;
ocorrenciaRel.Serie = ocorrencia.Serie;
ocorrenciaRel.DataHoraAgendada = ocorrencia.DataHoraAgendada;
ocorrenciaRel.DataHoraAtendimento = ocorrencia.DataHoraAtendimento;
ocorrenciaRel.DataHoraFechamento = ocorrencia.DataHoraFechamento;
ocorrenciaRel.Status = ocorrencia.Status?.Descricao;
ocorrenciaRel.Solucao = ocorrencia.Solucao?.Descricao;
ocorrenciaRel.Observacao = ocorrencia.Observacao;
ocorrenciaRel.Conclusao = ocorrencia.Conclusao?.Descricao;
ocorrenciaRel.OrdemServico = ocorrencia.OrdemServico;
ocorrenciaRel.Orcamento1 = ocorrencia.NumOrcamento;
ocorrenciaRel.Orcamento2 = ocorrencia.NumOrcamento2;
ocorrenciaRel.CedulasProcessadas = ocorrencia.CedulasProcessadas;
ocorrenciaRel.Tecnico = ocorrencia.OcorrenciaTecnico?.FirstOrDefault().Nome;
ocorrenciaRel.CobrarDeslocamento = ocorrencia.CobrarDeslocamento ? "Sim" : "Não";
ocorrenciaRel.CobrarAtendimento = ocorrencia.CobrarAtendimento ? "Sim" : "Não";
```

É comum se deparar com esses problemas e você pode contornar de maneiras diferentes. Alguns já deram algumas sugestões nas outras respostas que evitam que seu código quebre. [Reforçando que é sempre importante verificar se uma propriedade é nula antes de utiliza-la](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Eu costumo, em alguns casos que sei que pode ocorrer algum problema na atribuição dos dados já manter da forma que dei o exemplo acima. Pois a forma que está no seu código (dependendo da classe) se torna uma desvantagem depurar e localizar o problema no código. Então avalie no seu caso oque é melhor.

Em outros casos, você pode trocar para a forma que dei o exemplo apenas para localizar o problema e voltar a instanciar como antes, se achar que o código está seguro e de fácil entendimento (não acho a forma mais elegante, veja abaixo).

Para seu caso específico eu optaria por usar um public `static explict operator` pois você está, basicamente fazendo uma conversão de um método para outro que possui características muito parecidas.

*Para simplificar esse exemplo utilizarei classes menores de exemplo:*

**Classe (Entidade) de exemplo:**

```
public class MinhaEntidade
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Prop3 { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator MinhaEntidade(MinhaEntidadeDTO entidadeDTO)
    {
        return new MinhaEntidade
        {
            Id = entidadeDTO.Id,
            Prop1 = entidadeDTO.Prop1,
            Prop2 = entidadeDTO.Prop2,
            Prop3 = entidadeDTO.Prop3,
        };
    }
}
```

**Classe (DTO) exemplo:**

```
public class MinhaEntidadeDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Prop3 { get; set; }
    //Propriedade não utilizada na conversão da classe. 
    //As classes não precisam ter as mesmas proprieades para utlização do explicit operator
    public DateTime? PropXYZ { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator MinhaEntidadeDTO(MinhaEntidade entidade)
    {
        return new MinhaEntidadeDTO
        {
            Id = entidade.Id,
            Prop1 = entidade.Prop1,
            Prop2 = entidade.Prop2,
            Prop3 = entidade.Prop3,
        };
    }
}
```

**Converter de uma entidade pra outra ficaria simples assim:**

```
MinhaEntidadeDTO entidadeDTO = (MinhaEntidadeDTO )_db.MinhaEntidade
                                .Where(id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
```

A grande vantagem é **não precisar repetir o código** para converter o objeto de um pro outro sempre que for realizar essa operação. E você pode alterar o método validando os dados com as dicas que dei anteriormente e/ou utilizar da forma que dei o primeiro exemplo no método `static explict operator` facilitando a depuração.

[Entenda mais sobre o **explict** lendo a documentação da Microsoft.](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit)

Comment: É, eu sempre acabo fazendo isso, mas não existe uma forma de não ter que fazer isso?

Comment: @Taian, existem algumas outras formas de instanciar o objeto sim, pode ser um construtor onde você pode tratar esses dados que podem dar algum problema, um método, mas no final das contas vai ser algo parecido e não acho que será mais fácil pra você. Vou complementar um pouco a resposta dando algumas dicas

Comment: @Taian, atualizei a resposta. Espero que te ajude.

Answer (score 2):

Pouco tempo atrás, também tive o mesmo problema, a única solução que encontrei foi primeiro instanciar e depois setar para as propriedades.

Comment: @LeAndrade Porque não responde a pergunta? ele disse que a solução foi instanciar, talvez pudesse ter adicionado exemplo como o George, mas ainda responde

Comment: @Barbetta Removi a revisão, mas, para mim já que não exemplificou com código, poderia muito bem ser apenas um comentário na pergunta.

Comment: @Barbetta Quer dizer que para eu responder uma pergunta, tenho que apresentar linhas de código? A maneira que o Taian fez a citação está correta e respondi sua dúvida. Não necessariamente apresentando código.

Comment: Augusto, na verdade é só uma dica do @Barbetta ... Estamos apenas presando por repostas mais completas e exemplificadas na comunidade. Como ele mesmo disse, sua colocação ainda é válida. :)

Comment: @AugustoHenrique Você tinha recebido uma sinalização, eu questionei a sinalização. Sua resposta é valida, fica melhor com exemplos em código, mas ainda é valida.

Comment: Entendo @Barbetta, fica ressaltado que sou recente na comunidade. Vou aprender, rs!

Comment: @AugustoHenrique Seja bem vindo :D não se esqueça de fazer o [tour] e é possível acompanhar as discussões sobre funcionamento do so-pt no [Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Valeu, o Meta não sabia que existia.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um método auxiliar para lhe permitir fazer o debug.

```
T BreakMe<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    Debugger.Break();
    return func();
}
```

Usaria assim:

```
var ocorrencias = _db.Ocorrencia.AsEnumerable().Select(ocorrencia => new OcorrenciaRelatorioDTO
{
    Id = BreakMe(() => ocorrencia.Id),
    Ocorrencia = BreakMe(() => ocorrencia.NumOcorrencia),

    //...

}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use uma sobrecarga do método estático [IsNotNull](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isnotnull?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) das classe [Assert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) no namespace [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting?view=mstest-net-1.2.0).

A classe `Assert` é uma coleção de métodos auxiliares que visam testar várias condições. Se a condição que está sendo testada não for atendida, uma exceção será lançada.

`IsNotNull` testa se o objeto especificado é não nulo e lança uma exceção se for nulo.

```
Assert.IsNotNull(ocorrencia.Id);
ocorrenciaRel.Id = ocorrencia.Id;
Assert.IsNotNull(ocorrencia.NumOcorrencia);
ocorrenciaRel.Ocorrencia = ocorrencia.NumOcorrencia;
Assert.IsNotNull(ocorrencia.Protocolo;
ocorrenciaRel.Protocolo = ocorrencia.Protocolo;
.
.
.
```