# Erro instanciando classe System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: c#

Bom dia, alguém consegue achar o erro que estou cometendo ao instanciar?
Recebo essa mensagem de volta:

> Method error: Render : System.NullReferenceException: Referência de
>   objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.    em
>   AutoPhaseRun.Enabler.Enabled()    em
>   AutoPhaseRun.AutoPhaseRun.Render()    em
>   PoeHUD.Plugins.BasePlugin._Render()

Classe:

```
using PoeHUD.Poe.Components;
using System;
using PoeHUD.Plugins;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PoeHUD.Controllers;
public bool Enabled() {
        if (GameController.Area.CurrentArea.IsHideout 
            || GameController.Area.CurrentArea.IsTown 
            || !GameController.Player.IsAlive 
            || !Settings.Enable 
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.Data.LocalPlayer.GetComponent<Life>().Buffs.Exists(b => b.Name == "grace_period")
            || Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) == false)
            return false;

        if (GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.InventoryPanel.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.OpenLeftPanel.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.AtlasPanel.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.OpenRightPanel.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.SyndicatePanel.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.IncursionWindow.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.TreePanel.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.IngameUi.HiddenSkillBar.IsVisible
            || GameController.Game.IngameState.UIRoot.GetChildFromIndices(1, 111).ChildCount > 0)
            return false;

        else
            return true;
    }
```

Main:

```
using PoeHUD.Poe.Components;
using System;
using PoeHUD.Plugins;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using PoeHUD.Controllers;
public class AutoPhaseRun : BaseSettingsPlugin<AutoPhaseRunSettings>
    {
        private DateTime lasttime = new DateTime();
        Enabler enabler = new Enabler();

        public override void Render()
        {
            try
            {
                bool teste = enabler.Enabled();
                if (teste == false)
                    return;

                if ((DateTime.Now - lasttime).TotalSeconds > Settings.delay.Value)
                {
                    var buffs = GameController.Game.IngameState.Data.LocalPlayer.GetComponent<Life>().Buffs;
                    if (!buffs.Exists(b => b.Name == "new_phase_run"))
                    {
                        Keyboard.KeyPress(Settings.pressedKey.Value);
                        lasttime = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogMessage(e.Message, 3);
                LogMessage(e.Source, 3);
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Podia incluir os usings?

Comment: Veja se alguma dica nessa resposta te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369628/35358

Comment: Crie um break-point no primeiro `if` dentro do método `bool Enabled()`(acho que é um método cujo a classe foi omitida) e passe o ponteiro do mouse por cada instancia comparada dentro dentro dos dois `ifs`, ou então crie um quick watch para todos identificadores, com certeza algum é nulo.

Answer (score 1):

Faça debug e veja qual a instância que devia estar a ser instanciada e não está.

Se está a dar essa exceção então é porque está a tentar usar um objeto que não está instanciado.

**Por exemplo**

```
String s = null;
var i = s.Length;
```

> ERRO: [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Comment: A única coisa que descobri é que se na classe eu comentar tudo e deixar apenas "return true" ele funciona mas ainda assim não consigo achar o erro...

Comment: @ThiagoPiardi, a resposta do MauroAlmeida está correta, debugando você encontrará exatamente a linha do erro, pode ser inclusive que o erro esteja nas comparações no if, veja se é lá que quebra, depure seu cógido.

Comment: O problema é que eu não consigo executar esse código no VS por que ele é um dll

Comment: Como é que não consegue executar e consegue ver a mensagem de erro? compilou e executou na consola?